# Spark dataframe date_add function with case when not working

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark DataFrame in which I have a `where` condition to add number of dates in the existing date column based on some condition.

**My code is something like below**

```python
F.date_add(df.transDate, 
           F.when(F.col('txn_dt') == '2016-01-11', 9999).otherwise(10)
)
```

since `date_add()` function accepts second argument as `int`, but my code returns as `Column`, it throws error.

How to collect value from case when condition?

Comment: Try switching the order of the `date_add` and the `when`: `F.when(F.col('txn_dt') == '2016-01-11', F.date_add(df.transDate, 9999)).otherwise(F.date_add(df.transDate, 10))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pyspark.sql.functions.when()` returns a `Column`, which is why your code is producing the `TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable`

You can get the desired result by moving the `when` to the outside, like this:

```python
F.when(
    F.col('txn_dt') == '2016-01-11',
    F.date_add(df.transDate, 9999)
).otherwise(F.date_add(df.transDate, 10))
```